# How to remove bold blue outline color from folium.Choropleth within an folium.featuregroup on the map?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, folium

I have the following geodataframe called results:

[image: results info]

Calling `results.explore()` will result in the following leaflet:

[image: leaflet results]

My idea is to create 4 different layers using Featuregroups and Choropleth wherein I want to see what type of influence depot location have on total amount of km's within each area. The variables I want to compare are: `T*_depot_0`, `2_depots`, `3_depots`, and `4_depots`. I want to use the fill_color OrRd within each layer in order to distinguish high values with an darker red and lower values with lighter orange/yellow. By having layer control it would be able to click through the different Choropleth's and see the difference what different depots have on the total travel distance within each area.

My code:

```py
def add_depot_markers_featuregroup(depot_amount, featuregroup): 
    for i in range(len(depots_locations)):
        if i > depot_amount:
            break
        folium.Marker(
                [depots_locations[i].y, depots_locations[i].x], 
                popup="Depot_{0}".format(i+1),
                icon=folium.Icon(color='cadetblue', icon='solid fa-bicycle', prefix='fa')).add_to(featuregroup)

result_map = folium.Map(location=lat_long_groningen, zoom_start=11, tiles=None)

layer_depot_1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="1 depot", overlay=False).add_to(result_map)
layer_depot_2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="2 depots", overlay=False).add_to(result_map)
layer_depot_3 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="3 depots", overlay=False).add_to(result_map)
layer_depot_4 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="4 depots", overlay=False).add_to(result_map)

fs=[layer_depot_1, layer_depot_2, layer_depot_3, layer_depot_4]
for i in range(len(fs)):
    add_depot_markers_featuregroup(i, fs[i])
    depot_column_name = ""
    if i == 0:  
        depot_column_name = "T*_depot_{0}".format(i) 
    else: 
        depot_column_name = "{0}_depots".format(i+1)
    
    bins = list(results[depot_column_name].quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]))

    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        results, 
        data=results, 
        key_on='feature.properties.Postcode', 
        columns=["Postcode", depot_column_name], 
        fill_color="OrRd",
        fill_opacity = 0.8,
        line_opacity = 0,
        line_weight=1,
        bins=bins,
        legend_name = "T* per postalcode area based on depot {0}".format(i+1),
        name="T* of {0} depot per Postalcode area".format(i+1)).geojson.add_to(fs[i])
    
    geojson1 = folium.GeoJson(data=results, 
        name="tooltip " + depot_column_name,
        tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['Postcode', "Deliveries", "Area (km2)", "Number of cyclists", "Beardwood approx", depot_column_name], labels=True, sticky=True)
    ).add_to(choropleth)
   
# folium.TileLayer('cartodbdark_matter',overlay=True,name="dark mode").add_to(result_map)
folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron',overlay=True, control=False, name="T*").add_to(result_map)
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(result_map)
result_map.save("lastmile.html")
result_map
```

So, the good news is the layers work. The bad news is that I have very bold blue lines between the different polygons and multigons on the map, which I don't know how to change/remove. I've tried setting the `line_color="black"` of the Choropleth, but that didn't work.

[image: Current result]

How to remove/change/minimize the bold blue outline colors within each featuregroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no data is presented, I quote the [official sample](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb). The line decoration of the polygon's outline is defined by the style function. The sample defines color, line width, and dashed lines. Line width is set by 'weight'.

```
import json
import requests
import folium

url = ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/main/examples/data")
us_states = f"{url}/us-states.json"

geo_json_data = json.loads(requests.get(us_states).text)

m = folium.Map([43, -100], zoom_start=4)

folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        "fillColor": "#ffff00",
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 2,
        "dashArray": "5, 5",
    },
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me really well, I've added styling function to geojson1 variable that I add to each choropleth and the outline borders are now how I want it. Thank you!